# Negative number with decimals to positive number in PHP

Tags: php, decimal

I'm creating an import based on xml. From the XML i get some values wich are negative amounts like -316.65.

Before I save this values to the database I have to convert them to positive amounts. I've tried the following:

```
$amount = $inkoopfactuur->td[7] * -1;
```

This worked but, the decimals where gone.

Is there a way to convert this witouth losing the decimals?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a guess, multiply by 1.0 instead of 1.

Comment: floatval($inkoopfactuur->td[7]) to retain the decimals before using abs()

Comment: Thanks this worked but it replaced the . for a , Like this -100.95 to this 100,95

Comment: floatval() replaced a dot with a comma??? What it does is casts a string to a float, commas don't come into it#

Comment: @MarkBaker, Yes thats correct!

Comment: $x = floatval($inkoopfactuur->td[7]); var_dump($x); and show me the result with a comma in it!

Comment: Yes the result gives me a comma but I want to have a dot.

Comment: The result of $amount = floatval($inkoopfactuur->td[7]); does NOT give you a comma! Something else might, but that simple function definitely does not.

Comment: Well, I tried this for an example and it gives me the same results: $amount = floatval('-315.16') * -1; echo $amount.'<br>'; If I use this code in a new php file I dont get a comma. So there is something in my code causing that problem

Comment: Use var_dump() rather than echo when debugging, because it gives you a lot more information about your variables such as data type.

Comment: float(119) float(4284) float(314,76) float(2368,1) float(1552,95) float(4284) float(1785) float(-119) This is what I get

Comment: Funny thing is. When I dont convert the value I get the decimals so i dont get rounding values

Comment: maybe something in your locale settings when it comes to displaying the value: but the value is still a float with the decimals

Comment: Yes probably, Well thanks for you time and your answer!

Answer (score 5):

There's a better way to do this:

```
$amount = abs($inkoopfactuur->td[7]);
```

However, it could be the case that the integer rounding is the result of something else -- there's not enough information in the question to be certain.

Comment: Thanks but I still got the rounding. After using the function I save the result directly into the database

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a different locale.

Check [localeconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php)